# Method DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY (Oracle) to string

Tags: oracle11g

I'd like to convert an array of string elements into a single string, is there any way to do it?:

```
select
  cast(
    collect(
      '{' || 
      '"Id":' || to_char(LKP.Id) || ',' ||
      '"descImpuesto":"' || LKP.description ||
      '},'
    ) as sys.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY
  ) as ARRAY_LKP
from (
  select 1 as id, 'A' as description from dual union all
  select 2, 'B' from dual union all
  select 3, 'C' from dual union all
  select 4, 'D' from dual union all
  select 5, 'E' from dual
  ) LKP
```

I am using Oracle 11g database.

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you have an existing `DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY` that you have to manipulate, or are you creating it as you've shown and immediately want it a different format? i.e. is the `DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY` actually needed or just what you think you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're starting from an existing array you can use a table expression to get the elements:

```
select *
from table (
  select
    cast(
      collect(
        '{' || 
        '"Id":' || to_char(LKP.Id) || ',' ||
        '"descImpuesto":"' || LKP.description ||
        '},'
      ) as sys.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY
    ) as ARRAY_LKP
  from (
    select 1 as id, 'A' as description from dual union all
    select 2, 'B' from dual union all
    select 3, 'C' from dual union all
    select 4, 'D' from dual union all
    select 5, 'E' from dual
    ) LKP
  )
/

Result Sequence            
---------------------------
{"Id":1,"descImpuesto":"A},
{"Id":2,"descImpuesto":"B},
{"Id":3,"descImpuesto":"C},
{"Id":4,"descImpuesto":"D},
{"Id":5,"descImpuesto":"E},
```

... and then aggregate them together; using your example as an inline view:

```
select listagg(column_value, null) within group (order by null) AGG_LKP
from table (
  select
    cast(
      collect(
        '{' || 
        '"Id":' || to_char(LKP.Id) || ',' ||
        '"descImpuesto":"' || LKP.description ||
        '},'
      ) as sys.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY
    ) as ARRAY_LKP
  from (
    select 1 as id, 'A' as description from dual union all
    select 2, 'B' from dual union all
    select 3, 'C' from dual union all
    select 4, 'D' from dual union all
    select 5, 'E' from dual
    ) LKP
  )
/

AGG_LKP                                                                                                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"Id":1,"descImpuesto":"A},{"Id":2,"descImpuesto":"B},{"Id":3,"descImpuesto":"C},{"Id":4,"descImpuesto":"D},{"Id":5,"descImpuesto":"E},
```

Because you have the commas in your array values the final string ends with a comma; you can use `trim()` to get rid of that if you don't want it. Or if you can omit it from the array values you can use a delimiter as part of the `listagg()` instead (as shown below). As they're slightly misformed in your example anyway it's hard to tell what you're really dealing with.

If you're only creating the array for this purpose then you can skip it and aggregate the data directly:

```
select
  listagg(
    '{' || 
    '"Id":' || to_char(LKP.Id) || ',' ||
    '"descImpuesto":"' || LKP.description ||
    '}'
  , ',') within group (order by LKP.Id) as AGG_LKP
from (
  select 1 as id, 'A' as description from dual union all
  select 2, 'B' from dual union all
  select 3, 'C' from dual union all
  select 4, 'D' from dual union all
  select 5, 'E' from dual
  ) LKP
/

AGG_LKP                                                                                                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"Id":1,"descImpuesto":"A},{"Id":2,"descImpuesto":"B},{"Id":3,"descImpuesto":"C},{"Id":4,"descImpuesto":"D},{"Id":5,"descImpuesto":"E}
```

`listagg()` is available from 11g Release 2.

---

> it doesn't support more than 4000 characters in its output

You need to work with CLOBs, either through your own procedure to build up the string, or with a [user-defined aggregate function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/aggr_functions.htm); or you can use `xmlagg()`:

```
select rtrim(
  xmlcast(xmlagg(xmlelement(e,
    '{' || 
    '"Id":' || to_char(LKP.Id) || ',' ||
    '"descImpuesto":"' || LKP.description ||
    '}'
  , ',')) as clob), ',') as AGG_LKP
from (
  select 1 as id, 'A' as description from dual union all
  select 2, 'B' from dual union all
  select 3, 'C' from dual union all
  select 4, 'D' from dual union all
  select 5, 'E' from dual
  ) LKP
/

AGG_LKP                                                                                                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"Id":1,"descImpuesto":"A},{"Id":2,"descImpuesto":"B},{"Id":3,"descImpuesto":"C},{"Id":4,"descImpuesto":"D},{"Id":5,"descImpuesto":"E},
```

Again the XML aggregation leaves a trailing comma, which the `rtrim()` call removes.

---

It *looks* like you're manually manipulating JSON data; you might want to investigate [the PL/JSON package](https://github.com/pljson/pljson) as an alternative, since native support for JSON doesn't appear until 12c.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. Using listagg was one of my first approachs to solve the query, but unfortunatelly it doesn't support more than 4000 characters in its output so it doesn't fit with my needs.

Comment: Right, but that's a varchar2 limitation, so you'll hit that however you try to form the final string. You need to generate a CLOB, either from a stored procedure that queries the data and builds the CLOB up element by element, or with a [user-defined aggregate function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/aggr_functions.htm). There's an example [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques) that you can convert to use CLOB instead. But I'd look at PL/JSON still...

Comment: @JaimeDrq - added an XML technique that might work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much @Alex for your support. Indeed, the xmlcast can be converted to string just with a simple to_char method. However, I have seen that the xmlcast, compared with DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY objects, performs much more slower, so even the answer is valid for my question, I won't be able to use it because of this slow performance. DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY takes about 4 seconds to return one query which using xmlcast takes about 45 seconds to return the same output